# div element will not move to bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to make a JavaScript piano, with the keys being at the bottom of the screen, but setting `bottom: 0px;` doesn't work

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}


/*keyboard div*/

#keyboard {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 1366px;
  height: 90px;
  bottom: 0px;
}


/*keys, if those are important*/

#wk,
#bk {
  display: table-cell;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#wk {
  position: relative;
  height: 90px;
  width: 1.92%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#bk {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 52px;
  width: 58.05%;
  right: -9.04px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="keyboard">
  <div id='wk'>
    <div id='bk'></div>
  </div>

  <div id='wk' class=''>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want piano keys at the bottom of the screen or container? if you want to place it at the bottom of the screen you have to remove `position: relative;` Because that positions black container inside its parent. If you remove it add add to black container `bottom: 0;` it will be positioned inside body(which would be screen in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your styles as given below:

```
#keyboard {
    height: 90px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#0000FF;
}

/*keys, if those are important*/
#wk, #bk {
    border-color:#000000;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}

#wk {
    height:90px;
    width: 1.92%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#bk {

    height:52px;
    width: 58.05%;
    right: -9.04px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Dont set bottom since that will move it from down to up rather set:
top: 50%;

but since your width and height are odd use 41% to place it nicely

also its a nice practice to use em/rem or simply % and not px